# Search for the position of a specific dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

```
dict1 = {"1":"a" "2":"b" "3":"c"}
for dict2 in all_dict:
     if compare_dicts(dict1, dict2):
         ...
         ...
```

I need the index of the dict inside `all_dict` which is exactly the same like `dict1`.

Does the `for` loop go over `all_dict` sequentially so I can count the iterations inside the for-loop?

Comment: In your code above, `dict1` does not contain dictionaries. `compare dicts` is an invalid function since it contains spaces. Please clarify. (include more of your code)

Comment: try `enumerate(all_dict)`.

Comment: actually according to what you are saying, you just need `all_dict.index(dict1)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function yielding all indices of matching objects in a list using `enumerate()`:

```
def findall(lst, value):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x == value:
            yield i
```

You can apply this to your use case like this:

```
matching_indices = list(findall(all_dicts, dict1))
```

If you are just looking for a single match, the `list.index()` method is all you need:

```
matching_index = all_dicts.index(dict1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: x == dict1, all_dict)
```

This returns a list of all dictionaries you're looking for. Example:

```
>>> all_dict = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'a':1}]
>>> dict1 = {'a':1}
>>> filter(lambda x: x == dict1, all_dict)
[{'a': 1}, {'a': 1}]
```